# Hangs on build using nestjs, pm2

Tags: nestjs, pm2

I want to provide uninterrupted service using `nestjs`, `pm2`.

I download the changes via `git pull origin master` command.
After that, save the new changes through the `yarn build` command.
At this time, the service stops with an error saying `dist/main.js` cannot be found.

I tried to move the dist folder that was `build` outside the operating folder using `mv`, but it stopped and the service started again after entering the `reload` command.

Below is my code. How can I operate uninterrupted service?

```js
//ecosystem.config.js
name: 'my_api',
      script: 'dist/main.js',
      watch: '.',
      instances: 2,
      exec_mode: 'cluster',
      wait_ready: true,
      listen_timeout: 20000,
      kill_timeout: 5000


//package.json
"prebuild": "rimraf dist",
"start": "yarn build && pm2 start ecosystem.config.js",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the `watch:'.'`, the service did not stop during `build`,
and I was able to run it normally through the command `pm2 reload myApp`.

Comment: I have same issue. When I deploy my Project. I run `yarn build && pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js`. But downtime still happen when execute `yarn build`

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the dist folder before creating the build of the application. Stop the pm2 service and create a fresh build. After creating a fresh build. Restart the pm2 service. It will be fine.

Comment: thank you for your reply. What exactly is a fresh build?